# Share a user list between two Plone sites

Tags: plone-4.x

I would like to be able to share user list between two Plone sites.  Are there simple instructions on how to do that?  I have several sites that will have overlapping users, so it would be great if people could sign up for one site and be registered for other ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to maintain common userbase is to setup LDAP server and use LDAPUSerFolder. The are some downsides in this solution (LDAP groups vs Plone user groups), but it will work in many cases.

I am aware if there are any simple instructions, but google is your friend.